# Rollback Rx Encryption?

Tags: windows, encryption, system-restore

Does anyone know how the Rollback Rx snapshot encryption works or know where I can find detailed information on it. Here are some of the questions that come to mind... I am sure I could think of more.

1. What encryption type is used AES,Blowfish... 128-Bit, 256-Bit?
2. Is there a recovery method for encrypted files?
3. Does the pagefile/hibernate file get encrypted?

**This is the only information I can find on the subject**

Staff Member on forum [here](http://horizondatasys-forum.com/rollback-rx/710-encryption-options-rollback-xp.html)

> Truth be told - RollBack Rx snapshots are encrypted. In many cases, our corporate clients use RollBack Rx for this reason as well. If you had installed RollBack Rx onto your PC about 6 months ago... and continued to take regular snapshots etc.. If anyone where to remove your hard drive and place it into another PC as a slave drive and tried to access your files; they would only be able to see the files that existed 6 months ago. That is, they would only be able to see the files that existed on your original PC, before RollBack Rx was installed.

From Help File

> Rollback Rx system security prevents unauthorized access to the system and data by password protect Windows startup and encrypt snapshots. It secures your system and data from data thief even if the PC is stolen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I discovered that EAZ-Fix and Rollback Rx are the same product just marketed differently so I contacted EAZ-Fix for information on the encryption and they stated it was...</strike>

Symmetric AES 256-Bit Encryption and **only** the Snapshots are encrypted not the Baseline System.

Edit 1:

Finally got around to testing it some more. I created a VM, installed Rollback set up encryption and created some snapshots with files in them.

I used Plop to boot into Hirens Mini Windows XP and used Recuva on the drive. I was able to see and recover the files but they were encrypted so it seems to work in a similar fashion to EFS.

Edit 2:

**The encryption is useless**

When I restarted the machine Plop popped up again and I chose to boot off of Partition 1. This booted me into the system bypassing the password dialog which pretty much means the encryption is completely useless as the decryption key/password is stored on the drive in plain text. The system blue-screens after so much time but the files are still decrypted by booting directly into the partition using a boot manager :\